# Prototype inheritance, why an instance and not the prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've always wondered since i learned about prototype inheritance why you push an instance of the parent class into the child prototype and not the prototype itself?

```
var Animal = function(type){
    this.type = type;
}
Animal.prototype.getType = function(){
    return this.type;
}
var Cat = function(options){
    this.breed = options.breed;
}

//Inheritance
Cat.prototype = new Animal('Cat');
```

Why not do the inheritance like this?

```
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

My guess is that with only inheriting the prototype you aren't including the properties created in the constructor (this.type) but I'm not entirely sure. Anyone want to enlighten me?

But isn't putting an instance into the child class prototype putting all constructor-defined properties in the prototype too and thus introducing possible pitfalls? I'm thinking about the fact that the prototype properties are shared among all instances of a class unless they are defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, without thinking too hard about it, if one took the latter approach then the prototype chain wouldn't actually hold.  For example, let's assume that `Animal` inherits from `Entity`.  Then `Animal.prototype` would be *some* sort of pointer to `Entity` - and then

```
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
```

would set the prototype for Cat to the **same** prototype as Animal (i.e. some Entity reference).  This would have the effect of making Cat a *sibling* of Animal, rather than a *child* as intended.

Consequently, in order to establish the prototype chain properly, an *instance* of the parent class must be used, so as to be able to pick up the properties of that class.

Answer (score 4):

DANGER!!!

If you assign the prototype then they are the same object, any change to Cat.prototype will modify Animal.prototype

```
function Animal() { }
function Cat() { }
Cat.prototype = Animal.prototype;
Cat.prototype.legs = 4;
console.log(new Animal().legs + "!!"); // 4!!
```

Update:

By the way, to do a complete inheritance you must also inherit the constructor, calling it inside the parent:

```
function Animal() {
    this.onDie = new Signal();
}
function Cat() {
    Animal.call(this);
   // do your stuff here...
}
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
```

If not you will not get the properties the constructor injects into the instances as "onDie" on this case.

Comment: Great additions and explanation Matias!